# Can I remove the quantity option from a woocommerce product page?

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am using woocommerce bundled products.  Since the plugin won't let you create a bundle with product variations on the parent product, I am really using a bundled product as my "main" product (CD's) which can have a quantity.  Other attirbutes (set-up, barcode) are bundled with max quantity of 1.  I don't like the product add-ons plugin because it just uses meta tags.

Anyway, I want people to only be able to order 1 (max) of my parent product, but the plugin won't let you set a max for the parent product.  How do I set this, or (alternately) remove the quantity box from the parent product (but not the other bundled products)

Thanks.

I've tried product add-ons plugin

I don't have any.

Remove quantity choice from the parent (product page) in a product bundle, but leave the quantity option available for bundled products.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow

There can be two options, or trying to find the right filter (if there is one) to remove this box from the page, or just using CSS to hide it.
Personally, for this situation I think CSS is enough, and a much easier and faster solution.

If you could post a link to the specific product page, I can help you define the CSS rule you need to add.

Comment: Yes I think css would be fine.  I don't want to set the product to the tag that only one can be purchased.  I'm selling custom CD bundles, and customers might want to purchase two of the same item, but with different artwork/media/whatever.  The only CSS I've found so far is to change the is_purchasable or the one item only tag, neither of which work for my purchase.  But yes, I want the quantity to disappear just like it does when you set a product to single purchase only.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I wanted.  This worked.

.quantity { display:none; visibility:none; }

My problem previously was that every plugin/etc I used affected ALL of the quantity boxes (I am using the product bundles plugin)  This line of code worked perfectly and only removes the last quantity box.

Comment: Ugh crud, I wasn't thinking...this works great for my bundled products, but also removes the quantity for other products that aren't bundled.  Is there a way to call this code only for certain categories?